# Share a Listener for a seekbar between multiple Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder if there will be a method to share let's say an OnSeekBarChangeListener like this:

```
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener SeekBarCarChanged = new
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {..}
```

between different activities which have the same seekbars with the same ID.
I wanna to achieve this

```
ActivityClass1
setOnSeekBarChangeListener for seekbar in activity1..Get the Listener method from a third class

ActivityClass2
setOnSeekBarChangeListener for seebar in activity2.. Get the Listener method from the same third class
```

Comment: Let you Activities class `implements` the seekbar listener and then set the listener to the seekbars.

Answer (score 1):

Well lets see for that,

take a class ActivityClass1 which extends Activity and implement your seekbarlistener in this class

```
class ActivityClass1 extends Activity {
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener SeekBarCarChanged = new
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {..}
}
```

then take your classes in which you want this listener and extend ActivityClass1 to them, For eg:

```
// I want to access the SeekBarCarChanged listeners in the following classes

class ActivityClass2 extends ActivityClass1 {...}
class ActivityClass3 extends ActivityClass1 {...}
```

and so on ....